# Show data that are linked to each other in separate tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a newbie so I apologize if I'm not asking this question in the best way possible.
Let's say I have two tables: One called `CatColours` and one called `Cats`

`CatColours`

```
  id colour  spots
  -- -----   -----  
  1  brown   Yes
  2  black   No
  3  white   No
  4  orange  Yes
```

`Cats`

```
  id cat_name   
  -- ----     
  1  Jimmy 
  2  Shadow 
  3  Snowball   
  4  Lucky
```

So **id** in the *CatColours* table would be the primary key, and the values of the column **colours** correspond to the **id** number.
In the second table *Cats*, we have **cat_names** as well as **id** which would be a Foreign key (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I want to compose a query that would display **id** in the second table *Cats* as **colour** from the first table *CatColours* where the data will still correspond to the correct cat 
(ie. **id** 1 in *CatColours* is corresponded to the value BROWN as well as **spots**, however I'm not concerning myself with the values under **spots** at the moment. **id** 1 in *Cats* corresponds to JIMMY. 
When I query, I want to display **id** 1 as BROWN in the second table *Cats* to the **cat_name** that the **id** corresponded to, and so on for the rest of the cats.)

I hope this makes sense, please ask me if there needs to be clarification.
I just want to run a statement that will retrieve and summarize this data, not modify or change any tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just looking for a simple join:

```
SELECT CatColours.id, Cats.cat_name, CatColours.colour
FROM CatColours
INNER JOIN Cats ON CatColours.id = Cats.id
```

And [here's a SQL Fiddle to demonstrate](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a5bf/1).

For more information on joins, see also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

---

Honestly though I would switch the FK relationship around and make Cats (with their names) be the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 SELECT C.id, C.cat_name, CC.colour, CC.spots
 FROM cats C
 INNER JOIN CatColours CC ON
 C.id = CC.id
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your request, Cats table is the master table and CatsColor is the associate table. Cats.id is the Primary key for Cats and CatsColor.id will be the foreign key that refernces the Cats.id in the table Cats.

And the Query will be

SELECT cc.color, c.cat_name
FROM Cats c
INNER JOIN CatColours cc ON c.id = cc.id

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the data form existing tables you can use any of the queries already posted.

Pls note that your tables are not very well organized.

How would you represent a cat named Jimmy that is brown and doesn’t have spots? 
Also, note that your CatColors table contains redundant data because cat can have one color with our without spots so you are entering more dta than you need

I’d suggest you fix your tables like this

CatColors

```
id  color

1   brown

2   white

3   black

4   organge

5   gray....
```

Cats

```
id  name    color_id    spots

1   Jimmy   1          1

2   Shadow  2          0

3   Lucky   2          1
```

Here is a good tutorial you can read about table normalization that will give you some theoretical background on this

http://dotnetanalysis.blogspot.com/2012/01/database-normalization-sql-server.html